# Why is the finally statement needed if there is no catch block?

Tags: java, exception

I know that `try` statement is useless without `catch` or `finally`, and the `finally` clause is optional in a `try-catch` block. However, when I write a `try` statement without `catch` or `finally`, the compiler suggests inserting `finally` clause to complete try statement.

For example:

```
try {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(i[j]);
    }
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Catch");
} //no errors

try {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(i[j]);
    }
} //syntax error
```

Error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete TryStatement

at Driver.main(Driver.java:12)
```

Why is `finally` the only recommended statement to implement? Why not `catch`?

"I might want something to happen despite an exception being thrown, so I may not be looking to handle a specific exception in a specific way, but I may want to ensure that at least SOMETHING generic happens. If I can't handle it, at least do something." Looking for somebody to confirm on this.

Comment: If there's neither `catch` nor `finally`, why would you put a `try` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614473/does-it-make-sense-to-do-try-finally-without-catch

Comment: so try exists if and only if catch or finally does? So they're interdependent..

Comment: @DenysSéguret you put a try without a catch or finally in try-with-resources (although that's not what is here, obviously; just saying that's an example of where you would).

Comment: @AndyTurner Good observation

Comment: @JohnDoe I suspect you are using Java 6 or earlier (since the error message for 7+ is `error: 'try' without 'catch', 'finally' or resource declarations`). You might want to consider upgrading, since Java 6 reached end-of-life nearly 2 years ago.

Comment: I have reopened the question, since it's not a duplicate of the suggested question.

Answer (score 1):

Because a `try` without a `catch` or a `finally` makes no sense at all. It just does **nothing** so you'd have the same result if you just omit the try-block.

Answer (score 0):

It's required that a `try` statement has either a `catch` or `finally` clause because it would make very little sense in having a `try` statement without it.

The whole idea with the `try` statement is that there is some kind of handling to be done if the try-block throws exception. This handling can either be to catch an exception (using `catch`) or do something after the block has finished or an exception has been thrown (using `finally`). Then to have no such action associated with the `try` statement makes the `try` statement pointless.

Comment: It would be nice if one explains why one downvotes answers. Is there a problem with the answer? If the problem was explained the answer could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a `try` not followed by a `catch` or a `finally`
In order to fix it add a `catch` or a `finally` or both like this:

```
try{
    for(int j = 0; j <= i.length; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(i[j]);
    }
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
    System.out.println("Catch");
}//no errors

try{
    for(int j = 0; j <= i.length; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(i[j]);
    }
}//syntax error
catch(Exception e) {
// ... handle errors ...
} finally {
// ... cleanup that will execute whether or not an error occurred ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: he made an edit, this answer was proper to his original question.

Comment: his original question wasn't clear and his code not even compiled. I answered with a fix.

Answer (score 0):

`finally` guarantees the code in `finally` block always execute no matter there's exceptions or not, and you can write cleancode in `finally` block except handling exceptions, for example close a file or close a socket in it.  `try-catch` is for a caught exception that you can fix it locally.